# Can the Raspberry Pi 3 be used to create an iBeacon?

Tags: bluetooth

The new Raspberry Pi 3 features and integrated bluetooth 4.0 module. Is it necessary to purchase a different Bluetooth 4.0 dongle that's compatible with Bluez (used to create an iBeacon) or does the integrated module work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [tutorial](http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/05/create-an-ibeacon-transmitter-with-the-raspberry-pi/) but skip the first 7 steps as bluez should already be installed.
this worked on a Pi 2 with a dongle and a recent raspbian image out of the box:

```
hciconfig hci0 up
hciconfig leadv 3
hciconfig noscan
hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 63 6F 3F 8F 64 91 4B EE 95 F7 D8 CC 64 A8 63 B5 00 00 00 00 C8
```

please let us know how it works if you try it on a Pi 3.

Comment: just FYI, the one in comments does work with RasPi3: `hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 63 6F 3F 8F 64 91 4B EE 95 F7 D8 CC 64 A8 63 B5 00 00 00 00 C8 00`

Answer (score 2):

Specs say the built-in one works with BlueZ. Ubuntu MATE uses BlueZ by default to manage it: [(Link)](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-for-raspberry-pi-3/)