# Can Raspberry PI 3 transmit beacon signal?

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

[Raspberry PI 3 contain internal bluetooth 4 and BLE](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/raspberry-pi-3-specs-benchmarks/):

```
Specifications
SoC: Broadcom BCM2837
CPU: 4× ARM Cortex-A53, 1.2GHz
GPU: Broadcom VideoCore IV
RAM: 1GB LPDDR2 (900 MHz)
Networking: 10/100 Ethernet, 2.4GHz 802.11n wireless
Bluetooth: Bluetooth 4.1 Classic, Bluetooth Low Energy
Storage: microSD
GPIO: 40-pin header, populated
Ports: HDMI, 3.5mm analogue audio-video jack, 4× USB 2.0, Ethernet, Camera 
Serial Interface (CSI), Display Serial Interface (DSI)
```

**Can we use this chip to transmit beacon signals like iBeacon or Eddystone?**

I google it but I couldn't find any usefull tutorial. The result I find use bluetooth dongle for this purpose. Like [this tutorial](http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/05/create-an-ibeacon-transmitter-with-the-raspberry-pi/) and [this tutorial](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/11/29/feature_diy_apple_ibeacons/).

Comment: Please try this out with one of the tutorials and post an answer from your experience. I am curious about this but have other projects to do. My interest is from a retail point of view such as [How Bluetooth Beacons Will Transform Retail in 2016](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/kenny-kline/how-bluetooth-beacons-wil_b_8982720.html) or [25 Retailers Nailing it with their Proximity Marketing Campaigns](https://blog.beaconstac.com/2016/02/25-retailers-nailing-it-with-their-proximity-marketing-campaigns/).

Comment: looks like there are already answers to this question.  see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44112/can-the-raspberry-pi-3-be-used-to-create-an-ibeacon for instance.

Comment: Yes, the Pi3 can be used as an iBeacon using its internal Bluetooth.